# Express σ using matrix notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Suppose σ = (3, 4, 5)(2, 4, 5) ∈ S5.

(a) Express σ as the product of disjoint cycles.

(b) Find the order of σ.

(c) Is σ even or odd?

(d) Express σ using matrix notation.

(e) Find σ<sup>-1</sup>

Im not sure that I am doing this correctly...
for matrix notation I got:

2 3 4 5

4 4 5 3

but I didn't that that it could be a permutation because it is not isomorphic, and also, shouldn't 5 go to 2?
Can someone please explain to me how to set up the permutation in matrix form? From there it should be easy to find the disjoint cycles and transpositions and from there we can find whether it is even or odd. Basically I just need someone to explain to me how to set up the matrix....

Comment: Please use latex when posting on this forum http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: let's simplify your $\sigma$ to begin with.

Comment: Before you can do anything else, you need to know in which order you apply the cycles: do you apply first $(3,4,5)$ and then $(2,4,5)$, or do you apply first $(2,4,5)$ and then $(3,4,5)$. Both orders are fairly common, so you’ll have to tell us what your convention is. \\ I can tell you right off, though, that your matrix notation is not correct: it doesn’t specify what happens to $1$, and it sends $2$ and $3$ to the same place, $4$, meaning that it doesn’t represent a permutation.

Comment: From what I understand you start from the left and go right... So because it is an element of S5, the top row should read 1 2 3 4 5, but I don't know how to find the bottom row because 1 isnt in the permutation multiplication, and 2 apparently goes no where...

Comment: @Kaitlyn: Neither of the $3$-cycles affects $1$, so it goes to itself. The first $3$-cycle leaves $2$ alone — i.e., sends it to itself — and the second then sends it to $4$. The first sends $3$ to $4$, and the second then sends $4$ to $5$, so the composition sends $3$ to $5$. Can you finish it from there to complete the matrix form, which so far has $\binom{1\;2\;3}{1\;4\;5}$?

Comment: For the first part the second row would be:
                 
1 2 4 5 3 
and for the second:

                 1 4 3 5 2 
both would have a top row of : 1 2 3 4 5
and yes I know everyone is going to tell me to learn latex... I knew how to use it at one point and I will relearn how to use it after my final.

Comment: I’m not worried about the $\LaTeX$; however, I’m not sure what you mean by the first and second parts. Are we still talking about the matrix form of $\sigma$? Because its top line is just $12345$, and its bottom line starts $145$, not $143$.

Comment: Can I set it up into two different matrices that I described in my comment right above yours (the one I edited 10,000 times) and then multiply them through?

Comment: so I would end up with the bottom row being: 14523 for the product of the two matrices above.

Comment: @Kaitlyn: No: they won’t even be compatible for multiplication. The matrix of a permutation doesn’t represent it in the same way that the matrix of a linear transformation does: applying the permutation is not multiplying by the matrix. \\ Yes, $14523$ is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have the matrix form of $\sigma$, you can easily write it as the product of disjoint cycles. Start with the element $1$, and see what cycle it generates; since $\sigma(1)=1$, it generates the $1$-cycle $(1)$. Now go on to the first element of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ that isn’t already in a cycle: in this case that’s $2$, and it generates the $2$-cycle $(24)$, since $\sigma(2)=4$ and $\sigma(4)=2$. Repeat until every element of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is in one of the disjoint cycles that you’ve constructed. In this case you get $(1)(24)(35)$; it’s customary to omit $1$-cycles and write it as $(24)(35)$.

Now that we know that $\sigma=(24)(35)$, it’s pretty easy to find its order: how many times must you apply $\sigma$ to get the identity map? In other words, what’s the smallest positive integer $n$ such that the matrix of $\sigma^n$ is $$\binom{1\;2\;3\;4\;5}{1\;2\;3\;4\;5}\;?$$

It’s also easy to say whether $\sigma$ is even or odd, provided that you know the definitions of those terms in this context. Finally, if you got the order of $\sigma$ right, finding $\sigma^{-1}$ will be very easy.

**Added:** More generally, you can quite easily find the inverse of a permutation from its matrix form. Suppose that you have a permutation

$$\pi=\binom{1\;2\;3\;4\;5}{2\;5\;3\;4\;1}\;;$$

then $\pi$ is the function from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ that sends $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $5$, and so on. The inverse of that function just reverses the arrows, sending $2$ to $1$, $5$ to $2$, and so on. To get its matrix, flip the matrix for $\pi$ upside down to get

$$\pi=\binom{2\;5\;3\;4\;1}{1\;2\;3\;4\;5}\;,$$

and then sort the columns to put the top row in order:

$$\pi=\binom{1\;2\;3\;4\;5}{5\;1\;3\;4\;2}\;.$$